# Can someone please explain how is the setup stated below apparently causing amplitude resonance in spite of different frequencies?

Tags: waves, frequency, resonance, vibrations

Suppose I have a pendulum such that its natural frequency is $2 Hz$.

I release it from One extreme by striking it with a tuning fork of frequency $1 Hz$. Now in $0.5s$, the pendulum will undergo 1 full oscillation whereas the fork will undergo half an oscillation i.e. it will move away from its striking position. Then, when the pendulum returns to the same position after a second oscillation, the fork now returns to the striking position and hits it again.

Now let us consider none of the vibrations are being damped.

So, in this case, which apparently seems possible to me and whose validation I seek from those seeing this question, how is this amplitude increase being possible even though the bodies are not in resonance.